# AS3 Facebook.ui callback doesn't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook-ui

Today I'm going to use this method:

```
vardataObject:Object = {...}
Facebook.ui("stream.publish", dataObject, cb, "iframe");
function cb(res:Object):void
{
   ...do something...
}
```

I always use this method and it always work. But today the callback doesn't work!
Someonelse have the same problem?
Some days ago I know that it worked...

I'm using the API 1_6, but I've tryed with API 1_7 too.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with `Facebook.api()` method. It turned out that Facebook changed their api a bit and I had to change

```
if (Facebook.getSession() && Facebook.getSession().accessToken == null) {
    // code...
}
```

into

```
if (Facebook.getAuthResponse() && Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken == null) {
    // code...
}
```

and everything started to work again.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question even remotely.  Its like saying you found out the steering wheel needed fixed on your car when someone asks you how to change a tire.